# how to detect gesture for tap and long click with long click release gesture

Tags: java, android

I want to detect button gesture like tap  & long press with long press release gesture

I want this for a camera and video recording functionality

reference: https://github.com/Polidea/better-gesture-detector
work perfectly but I want all gesture for the button not for screen

Answer (score -1):

Try `view.setOnLongClickListener()` as per https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View.OnLongClickListener)

UI widgets on Android extend `android.view.View`